# C++ initializer list members still calling default constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization, shared-ptr, initializer-list

I'm having a problem initializing a `shared_ptr` member of a class I'm working on.

I have two classes, `A` and `B`:

```
class A {
  int _x;
  int _y;

  public:
    A(int, int);
};

A::A(int x, int y) {
  _x = x;
  _y = y;
}

class B : public A {
  std::shared_ptr<A> _a;

  public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<A>);
};

B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> a) : _a(a) {}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>(1, 2);

  B b(a);

  return 0;
}
```

I just want class `B` to hold a `std::shared_ptr` to an instance of class `A`.
However, I'm getting the error `no matching function for call to A::A()` in `B`'s constructor.

I'm confused because I thought the point of the initializer list is to avoid implicitly calling the default constructor for member variables, but it still seems to be trying to call `A`'s default constructor.

Any explanation is appreciated, thanks.

edit: after more messing around, it seems like it complies properly if `B` does not inherit from `A`. Still unsure why inheriting from `A` results in `A`'s default constructor being called from `B`'s constructor.

Comment: The default constructor of `A` is implicitly called in the constructor of `B`: `B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> a) : _a(a) {}`. Because `B` inherits from `A`  a constructor of `A` has to be called when `B` is constructed.

Comment: Why do you want `B` to inherit from  `A` **and** have a `shared_ptr` to `A` at the same time?

Comment: When you inherit from a class, every object of the new class contains an object of the superclass. `class B : A` means that each `B` *contains* an `A`. You need to initialize that object somehow. If you don't initialize it in the member initializer list (you aren't) then it defaults to using the default constructor, which doesn't exist. Therefore `B` must be rejected.

Comment: If you just want `B` to hold a `shared_ptr` to `A`, why is `B` derived from `A` which makes it do more than just hold a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @LouisGo that's what the OP already figured out: `it seems like it complies properly if B does not inherit from A`

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I'll remove my comment. Wasn't refresh the page when I commented it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `B` is derived from `A`, every `B` is an `A`. That means to construct a `B`, you must also construct an `A`. However, you do not tell `B`'s constructor how to construct an `A`, so the default constructor is used.

If you want `B` to be derived from `A` and only hold a `shared_ptr` to `A`, then `A` must not do anything you don't want `B` to do. Here, `A` has `_x` and `_y`.

It's not clear what you really want, but perhaps you want some other base class that both `A` and `B` derive from that only has what both `A` and `B` should have.

The classic example of inheritance in C++ is something like `Instrument` being the base class that has members like `Play` with derived classes like `Trumpet` and `Clarinet` having the thing that makes some particular instrument a trumpet. Only what is common to `Trumpet`s and `Clarinet`s should be in `Instrument`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! to give more detail on the purpose of both A and B: I'm currently learning about the decorator design pattern. In this example, `B` was a base decorator class, while `A` was functioning as a concrete class to be decorated. I ended up splitting `A` into two classes, one abstract base class and one concrete implementation ("plain", or undecorated) class, and have the decorator inherit from the abstract base class only. I fixed my compiler error, now I'm just focusing on not introducing any antipatterns :) thanks again

Answer (score 2):

When you call `B b(a);`, you construct a `B` object using the constructor `B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> a)`.

The issue is in your definition of this constructor. `B` inherits from `A`, meaning that `B` is not just a `B`, but instead is really an `A` and `B` stacked on top of each other. `A` is the base class, so it is on the bottom. So when you try to construct a `B` object, the code must first construct the `A` object at the bottom/base to form the foundation for the `B` object to exist on. That means that you actually have to tell the code how to construct the `A` object.

Because you defined a constructor for `A` that takes two `int` variables, the compiler does not generate a default constructor for `A`. Therefore, you must explicitly write out how `A` should be constructed within `B`. Constructing the `A` object can be done in the initializer list of the `B` object's constructor:

```
B::B(std::shared_ptr<A> a) : A(0,0), _a(a) {}
```

Comment: "Because you defined a destructor for A that takes two int variables", is destructor typo for constructor?

Comment: @LouisGo Yes, thank you! I've corrected the typo :)